# Magento 2: How do you move Catalog/CMS changes to production?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, deployment, workflow

The magento 2.2 documentation, in its [Pipeline Deployment Overview](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/#deployment-systems) , states the following (brackets & emphasis mine):

> [the production system is] Your live store. You should make minimal configuration changes here and **no changes to websites, stores, store views, products, or the catalog.** You should make all those types of changes in your development system.

I totally agree with that statement.

**My Question:**

After making and testing such changes on development store, how do I get those changes onto production?

Is there a best practice, or at least a recommended approach to this? I appreciate any help/insight.

For instance, are there a selection of tables for which I can write a migration script to safely execute each time I need to push content/catalog changes to production?

Answer (score 0):

Few things that i can suggest are below:

1.) Manually create everything on the live server.

2.) Develop or buy an extension if available that syncs the database tables data from your development environment to your production environment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have considered #1, but doesn't manually re-adding the updates to production fundamentally go against the rationale for making not changes on the live server? That approach makes me uncomfortable because it leaves some room for error (what if I botch a copy/paste job during the process of moving a larger batch of updates to the production server?). Additionally, it's like virtually doubling your workload, I feel like there should be an easier/safer way. As for #2, are there extensions out there for doing that sort of thing that you can recommend? Thank you again!

Comment: I can suggest you to export cms data from your development database and import it into your production database provided data is up to date in development server as per production server.